# Windows 7 Professional Un-bootable

Tags: windows, boot, system-restore

Laptop running Windows 7 Professional hangs on the 'Startup Repair' before booting into Windows. I have left this screen on for over 5 hours (searching for problems) and nothing happens (clicking cancel does not do anything either, it just hangs)

I have attempted to boot via safe mode/safe mode with networking/safe mode with command prompt (Startup Repair comes up and I get the same problem)

I inserted my Windows 7 Professional disc and launched off this. I selected 'Repair' instead of 'Install'. It hangs on the 'detecting window installations' screen (over 5 hours I have left it on this screen) and it does not detect my install.

Is there anyway to repair a Windows 7 system keeping in mind neither safe mode,repair of a install disc nor startup repair seems to be working.

Most examples I could find on the Internet said just insert the install disc and boot of this, that's all well and good but I can't get any further then 'detecting your windows installation'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, make sure the disc is healthy by scanning with the manufacturers diagnostic utility.

If that checks out, you could slave the drive and run a chkdsk on it or boot with some live media like BartPE to run chkdsk/recover files etc.

Chkdsk IME saves the day when it comes to more brutal booting issues.

Comment: I will give those suggestions a go. Thanks Scandalist

Comment: As a future reference, don't accept the answer unless it solved your problem.